# Dart: How can i calculate the average of a specific integer list out of X other integer lists with only one function

Tags: list, dart

I have a total of five lists for example:

```
List<int> list_1 = [1,2,3];
List<int> list_2 = [7,2,5];
List<int> list_3 = [8,6,9,4];
List<int> list_4 = [4,3,1,2,5,5];
List<int> list_5 = [4,4,3];
```

Now I want to be able to choose one trough the console or an input (I don’t know what’s best, or how that works).

The selected List should now be transferred into a function which returns the average.

Like so:

```
double average() {
  for(int i = 0; i < (list_3.length); i++) {
    calculation = list_3[i] + calculation;
  }
  return rechnung / list_3.length;
}
```

Now I have the average for list_3, but this is not dynamic at all. I‘d need to change the list manually in order to calculate the average of a different list. Following from this I need a function which calculates the average of the list I called before.

Is there some sort of dynamic way to solve this problem, that I don‘t need to create five functions calculating the average of one list? Any workaround to this:

```
double average_1() {
  for(int i = 0; i < (list_1.length); i++) {
    calculation = list_1[i] + calculation;
  }
  return rechnung / list_1.length;
}

double average_2() {
  for(int i = 0; i < (list_2.length); i++) {
    calculation = list_2[i] + calculation;
  }
  return rechnung / list_2.length;
}
...
```

More like this:

```
double average() {
  for(int i = 0; i < (list_$x.length); i++) {
    calculation = list_$x[i] + calculation;
  }
  return rechnung / list_$x.length;
}
```

I know this doesn’t work at all, that’s why I’m asking. :)

I‘d be very glad for an answer!!!

Comment: You need to make so `average` takes a `List` as parameter like: `double average(List<int> list) {`. You can then reuse the `average` method for all your lists.

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableIntegerExtension/average.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this works well for me under those circumstances.

```
List<double> list_1 = [1,2,3];
List<double> list_2 = [7,2,5];
List<double> list_3 = [8,6,9,4];
List<double> list_4 = [4,3,1,2,5,5];
List<double> list_5 = [4,4,3];

List<List<double>> averages = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5];

void main() {
  for (List<double> list in averages) {
    print(list.reduce((a, b) => a + b) ~/ list.length);
  }
}
```